# Unable to connect the API connection to the logic App via ARM template in terraform

Tags: terraform, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template, terraform-provider-azure

In my terraform I have created a logic app and its workflow with the help of a ARM Template. The 2 connections used in the logic app is also created via ARM template. But somehow even though the resources get created in AZURE. But when I got to the logic app, I always have to manually update the connection in the workflow. How can we make it automatic.

```
//First connection

resource "azurerm_template_deployment" "exampleeventhub" {
  name                = "acctesttemplate-44"
  resource_group_name = Resourcegrpname

 template_body = <<DEPLOY
{
    "$schema": https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#,
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "connections_eventhubs_name": {
            "defaultValue": "eventhubs",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
            "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
            "name": "[parameters('connections_eventhubs_name')]",
            "location": "qwerty",
            "kind": "V1",
            "properties": {
                "displayName": "eventhubconnection",
                "statuses": [
                    {
                        "status": "Connected"
                    }
                ],
                "customParameterValues": {},
                "nonSecretParameterValues": {},
                "createdTime": "aaaaa",
                "changedTime": "bbbb",
                "api": {
                    "name": "[parameters('connections_eventhubs_name')]",
                    "displayName": "Event Hubs",
                    "description": "Connect to Azure Event Hubs to send and receive events.",
                    "iconUri": "[concat('https://connectoricons-prod.azureedge.net/releases/v1.0.1480/1.0.1480.2454/', parameters('connections_eventhubs_name'), '/icon.png')]",
                    "brandColor": "#c4d5ff",
                    "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/1111/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/qwerty/managedApis/', parameters('connections_eventhubs_name'))]",
                    "type": "Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis"
                },
                "testLinks": []
            }
        }
    ]
}
DEPLOY
    deployment_mode = "Incremental"
  }
```

```
//Second connection
resource "azurerm_template_deployment" "exampledatacollector" {
  name                = "acctesttemplate-45"
  resource_group_name = Resourcegrpname
 template_body = <<DEPLOY
{
    "$schema": https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#,
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "connections_thengadatacollector_name": {
            "defaultValue": "thengadatacollector",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
            "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
            "name": "[parameters('connections_thengadatacollector_name')]",
            "location": "qwerty",
            "kind": "V1",
            "properties": {
                "displayName": "azuredatacollector",
                "statuses": [
                    {
                        "status": "Connected"
                    }
                ],
                "customParameterValues": {},
                "nonSecretParameterValues": {
                    "username": "764a2b1e-431d-4e90-87b1-ea6a34dac48f"
                },
                "createdTime": "aaaa",
                "changedTime": "bbbb",
                "api": {
                    "name": "[parameters('connections_thengadatacollector_name')]",
                    "displayName": "Azure Log Analytics Data Collector",
                    "description": "Azure Log Analytics Data Collector will send data to any Azure Log Analytics workspace.",
                    "iconUri": "[concat('https://connectoricons-prod.azureedge.net/releases/v1.0.1480/1.0.1480.2454/', parameters('connections_thengadatacollector_name'), '/icon.png')]",
                    "brandColor": "#0072C6",
                    "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/1111/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/qwerty/managedApis/', parameters('connections_thengadatacollector_name'))]",
                    "type": "Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis"
                },
                "testLinks": []
            }
        }
    ]
}

DEPLOY
    deployment_mode = "Incremental"
  }
```

```
//Logic App
resource "azurerm_template_deployment" "example" {
  name                = "acctesttemplate-46"
  resource_group_name = Resourcegrpname

 template_body = <<DEPLOY
{
    "$schema": https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#,
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "workflows_logicapp_name": {
            "defaultValue": "logicapp",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "connections_thengadatacollector_externalid": {
            "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/1111/resourceGroups/Resourcegrpname/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureloganalyticsdatacollector",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "connections_eventhubs_externalid": {
            "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/1111/resourceGroups/Resourcegrpname/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/eventhubs",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
            "apiVersion": "2017-07-01",
            "name": "[parameters('workflows_logicapp_name')]",
            "location": "qwerty",
            "properties": {
                "state": "Enabled",
                "definition": {
                    "$schema": https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#,
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {
                        "$connections": {
                            "defaultValue": {},
                            "type": "Object"
                        }
                    },
                    "triggers": {
                        "When_events_are_available_in_Event_Hub": {
                            "recurrence": {
                                "frequency": "Minute",
                                "interval": 3
                            },
                            "splitOn": "@triggerBody()",
                            "type": "ApiConnection",
                            "inputs": {
                                "host": {
                                    "connection": {
                                        "name": "@parameters('$connections')['eventhubs']['connectionId']"
                                    }
                                },
                                "method": "get",
                                "path": "/@{encodeURIComponent('thengaeventhub')}/events/batch/head",
                                "queries": {
                                    "contentType": "application/octet-stream",
                                    "maximumEventsCount": 50
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "actions": {
                        "Send_Data_2": {
                            "runAfter": {},
                            "type": "ApiConnection",
                            "inputs": {
                                "body": "@base64ToString(triggerBody()?['ContentData'])",
                                "headers": {
                                    "Log-Type": "testcustimlog"
                                },
                                "host": {
                                    "connection": {
                                        "name": "@parameters('$connections')['thengadatacollector_1']['connectionId']"
                                    }
                                },
                                "method": "post",
                                "path": "/api/logs"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "parameters": {
                    "$connections": {
                        "value": {
                            "thengadatacollector_1": {
                                "connectionId": "[parameters('connections_thengadatacollector_externalid')]",
                                "connectionName": "thengadatacollector",
                                "id": "/subscriptions/1111/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/qwerty/managedApis/thengadatacollector"
                            },
                            "eventhubs": {
                                "connectionId": "[parameters('connections_eventhubs_externalid')]",
                                "connectionName": "eventhubs",
                                "id": "/subscriptions/1111/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/qwerty/managedApis/eventhubs"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
DEPLOY
    deployment_mode = "Incremental"
  }
```

Comment: Hello @VVN, May i know  if you have referred the "Consent the OAuth connections" part in this document: https://www.bruttin.com/2017/06/13/deploy-logic-app-with-arm.html

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT - yes

Comment: May I know if  that powershell script helps you resolve the issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an expected behaviour , if you deploy the ARM Template, your both API Connections will have been created but inside logic apps you will have to update manually the connection by entering your credentials for the service. This is because for finalizing the API connection you need to give the consent but which is not possible in ARM template.

But if you need to finalize the API Connection creation without opening every Logic Apps then you can use PowerShell script .This script will retrieve a consent link for a connection for an OAuth Logic Apps connector. It will then open the consent link and complete authorization to enable a connection.

```
Param(
    [string] $ResourceGroupName = 'YourRG',
    [string] $ResourceLocation = 'eastus | westus | etc.',
    [string] $api = 'office365 | dropbox | dynamicscrmonline | etc.',
    [string] $ConnectionName = 'YourConnectionName',
    [string] $subscriptionId = '80d4fe69-xxxx-xxxx-a938-9250f1c8ab03',
    [bool] $createConnection =  $true
)
 #region mini window, made by Scripting Guy Blog
    Function Show-OAuthWindow {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
 
    $form = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Form -Property @{Width=600;Height=800}
    $web  = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser -Property @{Width=580;Height=780;Url=($url -f ($Scope -join "%20")) }
    $DocComp  = {
            $Global:uri = $web.Url.AbsoluteUri
            if ($Global:Uri -match "error=[^&]*|code=[^&]*") {$form.Close() }
    }
    $web.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = $true
    $web.Add_DocumentCompleted($DocComp)
    $form.Controls.Add($web)
    $form.Add_Shown({$form.Activate()})
    $form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
    }
    #endregion

#login to get an access code 

Login-AzureRmAccount 

#select the subscription

$subscription = Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId

#if the connection wasn't alrady created via a deployment
if($createConnection)
{
    $connection = New-AzureRmResource -Properties @{"api" = @{"id" = "subscriptions/" + $subscriptionId + "/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/" + $ResourceLocation + "/managedApis/" + $api}; "displayName" = $ConnectionName; } -ResourceName $ConnectionName -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/connections" -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $ResourceLocation -Force
}
#else (meaning the conneciton was created via a deployment) - get the connection
else{
$connection = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/connections" -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceName $ConnectionName
}
Write-Host "connection status: " $connection.Properties.Statuses[0]

$parameters = @{
    "parameters" = ,@{
    "parameterName"= "token";
    "redirectUrl"= "https://ema1.exp.azure.com/ema/default/authredirect"
    }
}

#get the links needed for consent
$consentResponse = Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -Action "listConsentLinks" -ResourceId $connection.ResourceId -Parameters $parameters -Force

$url = $consentResponse.Value.Link 

#prompt user to login and grab the code after auth
Show-OAuthWindow -URL $url

$regex = '(code=)(.*)$'
    $code  = ($uri | Select-string -pattern $regex).Matches[0].Groups[2].Value
    Write-output "Received an accessCode: $code"

if (-Not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($code)) {
    $parameters = @{ }
    $parameters.Add("code", $code)
    # NOTE: errors ignored as this appears to error due to a null response

    #confirm the consent code
    Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -Action "confirmConsentCode" -ResourceId $connection.ResourceId -Parameters $parameters -Force -ErrorAction Ignore
}

#retrieve the connection
$connection = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/connections" -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceName $ConnectionName
Write-Host "connection status now: " $connection.Properties.Statuses[0]
```

**Reference:**

[Deploy Logic Apps & API Connection with ARM · in my room (bruttin.com)](https://www.bruttin.com/2017/06/13/deploy-logic-app-with-arm.html)

Comment: can you please help with my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69037021/how-to-set-a-connection-string-for-web-app-in-arm-template-that-references-a-key

Comment: it should work automatically when using a ManagedServiceIdentity. However, I've found out that the API connection still is not able to be used because it's impossible to set "Access Policy" on the API connection through automated tools.