# How to create complex Logic App using Terraform

Tags: azure-logic-apps, terraform-provider-azure

I have created logic app which can handle log alert payload and compose the data and further do some ation like triggering Azure function.(below is the image i created from Azure Portal)

[image]

Straight to the point , How to create logic app (shown above) using Terraform.
Where i can Parse HTTPS response as Json and do Json Compose ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Logic Apps workflows via Terraform and Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70757669/logic-apps-workflows-via-terraform-and-azure)

Comment: No , I found simple approch for createing logic flows using azurerm_logic_app_trigger_http_request & azurerm_logic_app_action_custom Ref : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/logic_app_action_custom