# Using Terraform with azapi_resource Provider I'm Unable to Create a Slack Connection Returns "ApiNotFound"

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm, azapi

I'm attempting to convert an ARM template to Terraform that starts of by creating a Microsoft.Web/connections resource to Slack. I keep running into an issue that has me stumped. Using the following Terraform:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

provider "azapi" {

}

locals {
    name = "slack-notification-test"
    resource_location = "South Central US"
    logic_app_sku = "Standard"
    resource_group_name = "deleteme"
    slack_channel_name = "critical-alerts"
  
}

data "azurerm_subscription" "current" { }

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "group" {
    name = local.resource_group_name
    location = local.resource_location
}


resource "azapi_resource" "slackIntegrationAccount" {
    type = "Microsoft.Logic/integrationAccounts@2016-06-01"
    name = "${local.name}-slackIntegration"
    parent_id = azurerm_resource_group.group.id
    location = local.resource_location
    body = jsonencode({
            "sku": {
                "name": "Free"
            },
            "properties": {
                "state": "Enabled"
            }
    })
}

resource "azapi_resource" "slackConnection" {
    type = "Microsoft.Web/connections@2016-06-01"
    name = "${local.name}-slackConnection"
    parent_id = azurerm_resource_group.group.id
    location = local.resource_location
    body = jsonencode({
            "properties": {
                "displayName": "Slack",
                "statuses": [
                    {
                        "status": "Connected"
                    }
                ],
                "customParameterValues": {},
                "nonSecretParameterValues": {},
                "createdTime": "2022-09-20T17:10:26.9106346Z",
                "changedTime": "2022-09-20T17:10:37.870701Z",
                "api": {
                    "name": "${local.name}-slackConnection",
                    "displayName": "Slack",
                    "description": "Slack is a team communication tool, that brings together all of your team communications in one place, instantly searchable and available wherever you go.",
                    "iconUri": "https://connectoricons-prod.azureedge.net/releases/v1.0.1582/1.0.1582.2855/${local.name}-slackConnection/icon.png"
                    "brandColor": "#78D4B6",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/${data.azurerm_subscription.current.subscription_id}/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/${local.resource_location}/managedApis/${local.name}-slackConnection"
                    "type": "Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis"
                },
                "testLinks": [
                    {
                        "requestUri": "https://management.azure.com:443/subscriptions/${data.azurerm_subscription.current.subscription_id}/resourceGroups/${local.resource_location}/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/${local.name}-slackConnection/extensions/proxy/conversations.list?api-version=2016-06-01"
                        "method": "get"
                    }
                ]
            }
    })
}
```

I get the error "ApiNotFound" in the output, and the resource group and integration account are created but that is it.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked with following   with following code:

**main.tf**:

```
resource "azapi_resource" "slackIntegrationAccount" {
    type = "Microsoft.Logic/integrationAccounts@2016-06-01"
    name = "kavya-slackIntegration"
    parent_id = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.id
    location =  data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
    body = jsonencode({
            "sku": {
                "name": "Free"
            },
            "properties": {
                "state": "Enabled"
            }
    })
}

resource "azapi_resource" "slackConnection" {
    type = "Microsoft.Web/connections@2016-06-01"
    name = "kavya-slackConnection"
    parent_id = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.id
    location =  data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
    body = jsonencode({
            "properties": {
                "displayName": "Slack",
                "statuses": [
                    {
                        "status": "Connected"
                    }
                ],
                "customParameterValues": {},
                "nonSecretParameterValues": {},
                "createdTime": "2022-09-20T17:10:26.9106346Z",
                "changedTime": "2022-09-20T17:10:37.870701Z",
                "api": {
                    "name": "kavya-slackConnection",
                    "displayName": "Slack",
                    "description": "Slack is a team communication tool, that brings together all of your team communications in one place, instantly searchable and available wherever you go.",
                    "iconUri": "https://connectoricons-prod.azureedge.net/releases/v1.0.1582/1.0.1582.2855/kavya-slackConnection/icon.png"
                    "brandColor": "#78D4B6",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/${data.azurerm_subscription.current.subscription_id}/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/${data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location}/managedApis/kavya-slackConnection"
                    "type": "Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis"
                },
                "testLinks": [
                    {
                        "requestUri": "https://management.azure.com:443/subscriptions/${data.azurerm_subscription.current.subscription_id}/resourceGroups/${data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location}/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/kavya-slackConnection/extensions/proxy/conversations.list?api-version=2016-06-01"
                        "method": "get"
                    }
                ]
            }
    })
}
```

I received  the error

[image]

```
RESPONSE 404: 404 Not Found
│ ERROR CODE: ApiNotFound
│ --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
│ {
│   "error": {
│     "code": "ApiNotFound",
│     "message": "The API 'kavya-slackConnection' could not be found."
│   }
│ }
│ --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
│
│
│   with azapi_resource.slackConnection,
│   on main.tf line 191, in resource "azapi_resource" "slackConnection":
│  191: resource "azapi_resource" "slackConnection" {
```

When you define a custom API connection in Terraform, it seems it is not actually creating the API connection in Azure.

one may need to create the custom API connection resource in Azure manually by using Azure portal documentation, or programmatically using PowerShell or Azure CLI.

In my case I created api connection using resource `"azurerm_api_connection"`:

With the below ARM template , tried to create arm template deployment in terraform:

**example :**

```
data "azurerm_managed_api" "example" {
  name     = "servicebus"
  location = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
}

resource "azurerm_servicebus_namespace" "example" {
  name                = "acctestsbn-conn-example"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku                 = "Basic"
}

resource "azurerm_api_connection" "example" {
  name                = "kavya-slackConnection"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  managed_api_id      = data.azurerm_managed_api.example.id
  display_name        = "kavya-slackConnection"

  parameter_values = {
    connectionString = azurerm_servicebus_namespace.example.default_primary_connection_string
  }

  tags = {
    Hello = "World"
  }

  lifecycle {
    
    ignore_changes = [parameter_values]
  }
}
```

- Here I included   "kind": "V1",   set "connectionState": "Enabled",

snippet:

```
"kind": "V1",
  "properties": {
        "displayName": "kavya-slackConnection",
        "authenticatedUser": {},
        "overallStatus": "Connected",
        "statuses": [
            {
                "status": "Connected"
            }
        ],
        "connectionState": "Enabled",
```

main.tf:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment" "example" {
  name                = "exmpldeployment"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  deployment_mode     = "Incremental"
  template_content =  <<TEMPLATE
{   
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
  "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
  "name": "string",
  "location": "eastus",
  "kind": "V1",
  "properties": {
        "displayName": "kavya-slackConnection",
        "authenticatedUser": {},
        "overallStatus": "Connected",
        "statuses": [
            {
                "status": "Connected"
            }
        ],
        "connectionState": "Enabled",
        "parameterValues": {},
        "customParameterValues": {},
        "createdTime": "2023-03-29T15:07:04.2976682Z",
        "changedTime": "2023-03-29T15:07:04.2976682Z",
        "api": {
            "name": "servicebus",
            "displayName": "Service Bus",
            "description": "Connect to Azure Service Bus to send and receive messages. You can perform actions such as send to queue, send to topic, receive from queue, receive from subscription, etc.",
            "iconUri": "https://connectoricons-prod.azureedge.net/releases/v1.0.1627/1.0.1627.3238/servicebus/icon.png",
            "brandColor": "#c4d5ff",
            "category": "Standard",
            "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/servicebus",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis"
        },
        "testLinks": [],
        "testRequests": []
    }
    }
    ],
    "outputs": {
      "exampleOutput": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "someoutput"
      }
    }
}
TEMPLATE

  // NOTE: whilst we show an inline template here, we recommend
  // sourcing this from a file for readability/editor support
}
```

[image]

**Reference :** [Unable to connect the API connection to the logic App via ARM template in terraform - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68892355/unable-to-connect-the-api-connection-to-the-logic-app-via-arm-template-in-terraf) by @Ansuman Bal

Answer (score 0):

As @kavyaS mentioned using a azurerm_managed_api instead of azapi_resource. Here is a working snippet:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

provider "azapi" {

}

locals {
    name = "slack-notification-test"
    resource_location = "South Central US"
    logic_app_sku = "Standard"
    resource_group_name = "deleteme"
    slack_channel_name = "pfl-production-critical-alerts"
  
}

data "azurerm_subscription" "current" { }

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "group" {
    name = local.resource_group_name
    location = local.resource_location
}


resource "azapi_resource" "slackIntegrationAccount" {
    type = "Microsoft.Logic/integrationAccounts@2016-06-01"
    name = "${local.name}-slackIntegration"
    parent_id = azurerm_resource_group.group.id
    location = local.resource_location
    body = jsonencode({
            "sku": {
                "name": "Free"
            },
            "properties": {
                "state": "Enabled"
            }
    })
}

data "azurerm_managed_api" "slack" {
    name = "Slack"
    location = local.resource_location
}

resource "azurerm_api_connection" "slackConnection" {
    name = "${local.name}-slackConnection"
    resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.group.name
    display_name = "Slack"
    managed_api_id = data.azurerm_managed_api.slack.id
}
```