# Azure logic app with different connections deployment

Tags: deployment, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to deploy a Logic App in a certain azure environment but i'm facing a problem that i don't know how to give it solution.

The problem is that when I deploy these logic apps, the connectors that references to Microsoft accounts, like Office connectors or Dynamics 365 connectors are getting the following error:

[image: Invalid connection error]

Is there any way to specify the values for these connections in the parameters.json file of the Logic App? Like, a parameter where I can specify email and password using key vaults?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the connections like Office 365 using ARM template deployment but you will get **Invalid Connection** error because your connection is not authenticated yet.

- Office 365 API follows OAuth 2.0 authentication with ***Authorization Code*** grant type flow which needs user login to fetch the code. You can refer to this [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-technet-forums/6a17c729-ea15-4309-bd34-aa07d0a818bc) which says the same.

[image]

- I have used below code to deploy the logic app which creates the connection but its not yet authenticated.

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "logicAppName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
            "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
            "name": "[parameters('logicAppName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "identity": {
                "type": "SystemAssigned"
            },
            "properties": {
                "state": "Enabled",
                "definition": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
                    "actions": {
                        "Send_an_email_(V2)": {
                            "inputs": {
                                "body": {
                                    "Body": "<p>Hello, This is Afreen</p>",
                                    "Importance": "Normal",
                                    "Subject": "This is Test Email",
                                    "To": "{email_id}"
                                },
                                "host": {
                                    "connection": {
                                        "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365']['connectionId']"
                                    }
                                },
                                "method": "post",
                                "path": "/v2/Mail"
                            },
                            "runAfter": {},
                            "type": "ApiConnection"
                        }
                    },
                    "outputs": {},
                    "parameters": {
                        "$connections": {
                            "defaultValue": {},
                            "type": "Object"
                        }
                    },
                    "triggers": {
                        "manual": {
                            "inputs": {},
                            "kind": "Http",
                            "type": "Request"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "parameters": {
                    "$connections": {
                        "value": {
                            "office365": {
                                "connectionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', 'office365')]",
                                "connectionName": "office365",
                                "id": "[concat(subscription().id,'/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', resourceGroup().location, '/managedApis/office365')]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', 'office365')]"
            ]
        },
        {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
        "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "name": "office365",
        "properties": {
            "api": {
            "id": "[concat(subscription().id,'/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', resourceGroup().location, '/managedApis/office365')]"
            },
            "displayName": "office365"
        }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

- Once the logic app and the connection is created, you can validate them using the PowerShell script given in this [Github link](https://github.com/logicappsio/LogicAppConnectionAuth/blob/master/LogicAppConnectionAuth.ps1). while doing so, you will be asked to sign in for authentication. Upon successful completion, status of the connection will get changed from **Error** to **Connected**.

```
Param(
    [string] $ResourceGroupName = 'YourRG',
    [string] $ResourceLocation = 'eastus | westus | etc.',
    [string] $api = 'office365 | dropbox | dynamicscrmonline | etc.',
    [string] $ConnectionName = 'YourConnectionName',
    [string] $subscriptionId = '***********',
    [bool] $createConnection =  $true | $false
)
 #region mini window, made by Scripting Guy Blog
    Function Show-OAuthWindow {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
 
    $form = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Form -Property @{Width=600;Height=800}
    $web  = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser -Property @{Width=580;Height=780;Url=($url -f ($Scope -join "%20")) }
    $DocComp  = {
            $Global:uri = $web.Url.AbsoluteUri
            if ($Global:Uri -match "error=[^&]*|code=[^&]*") {$form.Close() }
    }
    $web.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = $true
    $web.Add_DocumentCompleted($DocComp)
    $form.Controls.Add($web)
    $form.Add_Shown({$form.Activate()})
    $form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
    }
    #endregion

#login to get an access code 

Login-AzureRmAccount 

#select the subscription

$subscription = Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId

#if the connection wasn't alrady created via a deployment
if($createConnection)
{
    $connection = New-AzureRmResource -Properties @{"api" = @{"id" = "subscriptions/" + $subscriptionId + "/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/" + $ResourceLocation + "/managedApis/" + $api}; "displayName" = $ConnectionName; } -ResourceName $ConnectionName -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/connections" -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $ResourceLocation -Force
}
#else (meaning the conneciton was created via a deployment) - get the connection
else{
$connection = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/connections" -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceName $ConnectionName
}
Write-Host "connection status: " $connection.Properties.Statuses[0]

$parameters = @{
    "parameters" = ,@{
    "parameterName"= "token";
    "redirectUrl"= "https://ema1.exp.azure.com/ema/default/authredirect"
    }
}

#get the links needed for consent
$consentResponse = Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -Action "listConsentLinks" -ResourceId $connection.ResourceId -Parameters $parameters -Force

$url = $consentResponse.Value.Link 

#prompt user to login and grab the code after auth
Show-OAuthWindow -URL $url

$regex = '(code=)(.*)$'
    $code  = ($uri | Select-string -pattern $regex).Matches[0].Groups[2].Value
    Write-output "Received an accessCode: $code"

if (-Not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($code)) {
    $parameters = @{ }
    $parameters.Add("code", $code)
    # NOTE: errors ignored as this appears to error due to a null response

    #confirm the consent code
    Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -Action "confirmConsentCode" -ResourceId $connection.ResourceId -Parameters $parameters -Force -ErrorAction Ignore
}

#retrieve the connection
$connection = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/connections" -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceName $ConnectionName
Write-Host "connection status now: " $connection.Properties.Statuses[0]
```

[image]

***References***-

[Unable to connect the API connection to the logic App via ARM template in terraform - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68892355/unable-to-connect-the-api-connection-to-the-logic-app-via-arm-template-in-terraf).

[Deploying in the Logic Apps Preview Refresh | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/logicapps/deploying-in-the-logic-apps-preview-refresh#what-about-oauth).

Comment: Thanks for this response! I could automate some of the process using the script that you shared to me, I modify my deployment script to verify the connections status and ask for authentication for the connections in error and it worked perfect for my case.